# Measuring the resistance of a button

Tags: automotive

I need to know the resistance value of buttons on a car steering wheel. Therefore, my question is: How do I measure the resistance of a steering wheel button using a digital multimeter? I don't currently have the multifunction steering wheel installed yet, so can I measure the resistance of the buttons without the steering wheel being installed and hooked into the ignition/electronic? I'm an electrical newbie, so any detailed instructions on how to measure the resistance of a button is greatly appreciated.

Thanks a million!

Comment: What resistance are you measuring? If you just want the button's resistance then you don't need it plugged up. Do you want the resistance of wiring and stuff too?

Comment: If the button setup is a standard resistor ladder, than yes.

Comment: While we're talking about it, it's never a good idea to check resistance of a live circuit - you might break something, and parallel paths mean you still don't necessarily know anything. Seen people break factories this way.

Comment: Why do you assume that the resistance is relevant for anything, or that you have any access to the buttons themselves? Most current cars with buttons on steering wheels have some sort of a digital bus coming out of the steering wheel, that carries the button presses/releases digitally. Do you have any reason to assume otherwise? I really worry that you will deploy your airbag by mucking around with a multimeter without full understanding what you're doing. At least get the original service manual for safe steering wheel removal procedure!

Comment: We need: **car year, make and model** and the part number/link to the **replacement steering wheel**. It's impossible to answer your question otherwise without potentially putting you and your passengers in a lot of danger.

Comment: As Kuba says, you could damage something or kill/injure yourself via triggering the airbag. Not to mention that triggering the airbag would total many cars given the cost of replacement. On my car you can apparently trigger the airbags individually via the OBDII interface using the (in)appropriate codes, let alone poking around with hardware.

Answer (score 1):

You could mess something up, poking around on a steering wheel, not knowing what you are doing. I think you need to re-examine what you are doing and why you are doing it. I cannot think of a single reason why anyone would need to measure the resistance of a button on a steering wheel. What follows is a general procedure for measuring things whose resistance is too small to measure with a regular Ohm meter or multi-meter.

If you need to measure the on-state resistance of a button (or the resistance of a battery contact or some such thing), a simple multi-meter will not help you. The resistance is probably much less than 1 Ohm. Volt meters have a problem with low Ohm measurements because the leads on the meter contribute almost as much resistance as the switch.

Generally what I find to be most practical is to use a lab power supply with current limit. I force a known current through the button (or whatever), and measure the voltage drop from terminal to terminal of the button with a Volt meter. This is a "four wire" measurement.

You have to decide how much current is reasonable. If you have no idea, you can start with 10 mA, and work your way up until the voltage is large enough to read accurately with the Volt meter.

Comment: I'd be very, very worried to tell someone who doesn't know what they're doing to muck with a lab power supply anywhere near a steering wheel. Someone might be killed. We know way too little at this point to suggest anything without it being potentially very dangerous.

Comment: @KubaOber, I added a warning. One thing you should keep in mind is that people find these questions via search. If someone searches for "how do you measure the resistance of a button" they are liable to find this post. It would be nice if such people came away with something more than a bunch of dire warnings.

Comment: It's not about measuring the resistance of just any button, though. Never mind that if a button's resistance significantly affects the function of the circuit, perhaps one is doing it wrong...

Comment: @KubaOber, I guess what I am saying is that I am not answering for the benefit of the OP. I doubt we will ever hear from the OP again. I am answering for the benefit of others who find this question later by searching. I think it is pretty obvious that the OP is out of his (or could be her?) depth.